# How can I simulate user input from a console?

Tags: c#, streamreader, windows-console

Im doing some challenges in HackerRank. I usually use a `windows Form` project in visualstudio to do the debug, but realize I lost lot of time input the test cases. So I want suggestion of a way I can easy simulate the `console.ReadLine()`

Usually the challenges have the cases describe with something like this:

```
5
1 2 1 3 2 
3 2
```

And then is read like: *using three ReadLine*

```
static void Main(String[] args) {
    int n = Convert.ToInt32(Console.ReadLine());
    string[] squares_temp = Console.ReadLine().Split(' ');
    int[] squares = Array.ConvertAll(squares_temp,Int32.Parse);
    string[] tokens_d = Console.ReadLine().Split(' ');
    int d = Convert.ToInt32(tokens_d[0]);
    int m = Convert.ToInt32(tokens_d[1]);
    // your code goes here
}
```

Right now I was thinking in create a file `testCase.txt` and use StreamReader.

```
using (StreamReader sr = new StreamReader("testCase.txt")) 
{
    string line;
    // Read and display lines from the file until the end of 
    // the file is reached.
    while ((line = sr.ReadLine()) != null) 
    {
        Console.WriteLine(line);
    }
}
```

This way I can replace `Console.ReadLine()` with `sr.ReadLine()`, but this need have a text editor open, delete old case, copy the new one and save the file each time.

So is there a way I can use a Textbox, so only need copy/paste in the textbox and use streamReader or something similar to read from the textbox?

Comment: Does .NET provide a high-level wrapper for [`WriteConsoleInput`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms687403)? This *should* be easy.

Comment: Regular "hackers" just use input redirect... My.exe <input.txt

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use the [StringReader](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.io.stringreader(v=vs.110).aspx) class to read from a `string` rather than a file.

Answer (score 1):

the solution you accepted! doesn't really emulate the Console.ReadLine(), so you can't paste it directly to **HackerRank**.

I solved it this way:

.

.

Just **paste this class** above the static Main method or anywhere inside the main class to hide the original *System.Console*

```
        class Console
        {
            public static Queue<string> TestData = new Queue<string>();
            public static void SetTestData(string testData)
            {
                TestData = new Queue<string>(testData.Split(new string[] { Environment.NewLine }, StringSplitOptions.RemoveEmptyEntries).Select(x=>x.TrimStart()));
            }
            public static void SetTestDataFromFile(string path)
            {
                TestData = new Queue<string>(File.ReadAllLines(path));
            }
            public static string ReadLine()
            {
                return TestData.Dequeue();
            }
            public static void WriteLine(object value = null)
            {
                System.Console.WriteLine(value);
            }
            public static void Write(object value = null)
            {
                System.Console.WriteLine(value);
            }
        }
```

and use it this way.

```
    //Paste the Console class here.
    static void HackersRankProblem(String[] args)
    {
        Console.SetTestData(@"
            6
            6 12 8 10 20 16
        ");


        int n = int.Parse(Console.ReadLine());
        string arrStr = Console.ReadLine();
        .
        .
        .
    }
```

Now your code will look the same! and you can test as many data as you want without changing your code.

**Note: If you need more complexes Write or WriteLine methods, just add them and send them to the original System.Console(..args)**

Answer (score 0):

Just set Application Arguments: <input.txt

and provide in input.txt your input text.

Be careful to save the file with ANSI encoding.

Comment: This does not answer the question that was asked. The whole point of the question is to avoid having an external file containing the user input, and instead to be able to incorporate the test data directly into the code. Never mind that this answer doesn't involve any sort of _programming_ problem, and so is off-topic here. It would possibly be suitable for an answer to a question on superuser.com, if it weren't for the fact that it's almost certainly not providing anything new to the corpus of answers on that site.